# Plot multiple grouped bar chart with matplotlib in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Here's few rows of my 100k lines df:
[`data.head()`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kodrg.png)

my goal is to have 4 grouped bar charts (1row ; 4 col) where :

- Each chart correspands to a "product family" (I know i have 4 so i can make 4 sub-df)
- **"Site"**  and **"year"** in *x axis*,
- "sum of **Tonnage**" in *y axis*,
  [Example of a the bar chart I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jWew.png)

The closest i got is to have the 4 plots but one under the other. and the code is not as elegant as i want it to be.

I'm a beginner so this might look too easy for you. just bare with me :)

Here's my code:

```
data_A=data_no_dp.loc[data_no_dp['Product family']=='A'][['id','Site','Tonnage','Année']].drop_duplicates('id')
data_B=data_no_dp.loc[data_no_dp['Product family']=='B'][['id','Site','Tonnage','Année']].drop_duplicates('id')
data_C=data_no_dp.loc[(data_no_dp['Product family']=='C') ][['id','Site','Tonnage','Année']].drop_duplicates('id')
data_D=data_no_dp.loc[(data_no_dp['Product family']=='D') ][['id','Site','Tonnage','Année','Product family']].drop_duplicates('id')

data_A_pivot=data_A.groupby(['Site','Année']).sum().unstack()
data_A_pivot=data_A_pivot['Tonnage'].replace(np.nan,0)

data_B_pivot=data_B.groupby(['Site','Année']).sum().unstack()
data_B_pivot=data_B_pivot['Tonnage'].replace(np.nan,0)

data_C_pivot=data_C.groupby(['Site','Année']).sum().unstack()
data_C_pivot=data_C_pivot['Tonnage'].replace(np.nan,0)

data_D_pivot=data_D.groupby(['Site','Année']).sum().unstack()
data_D_pivot=data_D_pivot['Tonnage'].replace(np.nan,0)


#plt.subplots(1,4, sharey=True, figsize= (20,4))

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
ax1=data_A_pivot.plot(kind='bar')
ax2=data_B_pivot.plot(kind='bar')
ax3=data_C_pivot.plot(kind='bar')
ax4=data_D_pivot.plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow? You mentioned that you got some code working, but it wasn't as elegant as you wanted it to be. Could you add this code to the question? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I added the code i have so far. Let me know what you think or if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no data were provided, I drew multiple graphs using test data from seaborn. pandas plots and subplots can be addressed with the following technique.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# for sample data
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
data_A = tips[tips['day'] == 'Sun']
data_B = tips[tips['day'] == 'Sat']
data_C = tips[tips['day'] == 'Thur']
data_D = tips[tips['day'] == 'Fri']
data_A_pivot=data_A.groupby(['time','sex']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
data_B_pivot=data_B.groupby(['time','sex']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
data_C_pivot=data_C.groupby(['time','sex']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
data_D_pivot=data_D.groupby(['time','sex']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)

fig, [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4] = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=4, figsize=(20,4))

data_A_pivot.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1)
data_B_pivot.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2)
data_C_pivot.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax3)
data_D_pivot.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax4)

plt.show()
```

[image]